# Shapefiles for all the individual countries in the world

Tags: shapefile

I'm searching for shapefiles that I can later convert into SVG (with something like kartograph.py). Essentially I'm just looking for the outline with (if possible) a dot where the capital is on the map.

Is there anywhere that I can download them all? Or is there a better solution than using shapefiles?

Comment: Natural Earth shapefiles http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Comment: Or DIVA-GIS has these on their website  http://www.diva-gis.org/Data

Comment: For SVG http://d-maps.com/continent.php?num_con=8&lang=en

Comment: @Mapperz Thank you, I know of that site but only found the world map. I could convert the shapefile to SVG and then split everything with regex on `<path>` but how do I distinguish which country is which? I don't want to do it manually of course. There's no `id` with each country name or anything of the kind.

Comment: @PROBERT Thakns, I've already seen that too :). Unfortunately they explicitly say it's for non-commercial use only and my purpose would be commercial.